# Google Test methods with fstream

Tags: c++, fstream, googletest

I want to write Google Test for method, that return `void` and take two arguments: filepath to file1 and filepath to file2. This method read some data in first file and create second file, where does this data write. For this i use `std::ifstream` and `std::ofstream`. In test i want call my method and then check, that second file was create:

```
TEST_F(ConverterTest, Convert) {
  converter.ConvertToBin(std::string("file1.txt"), std::string("file2.txt"));
  std::ifstream data("file2.txt");
  EXPECT_TRUE(data.is_open());
}
```

I create file1 and run test. But this test failed, because in method `ConvertToBin()` -`std::basic_ifstream.is_open()` failed (return false). Path to file1 exactly true.

```
#include <fstream>
void Converter::ConvertToBin(const std::string& src_path,
                             const std::string& dst_path) {
  input_stream_ = std::ifstream(src_path, std::ios::in);
  if (!input_stream_.is_open())
    throw(std::string("Error."));

  output_stream_ = std::ofstream(dst_path,
                                 std::ios::binary | std::ios::out);
  if (!output_stream_.is_open())
    throw(std::string("Error."));

  ...
}
```

Even if in my test i create only `std::ifstream` (don't call `converter.ConvertToBin()`), having previously created "file2.txt" in my directory, `data.is_open()` return false too. I'm sure I'm passing the right paths. Really i can't use fstream in GoogleTest? Or am I doing something wrong?

My test class:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include "src/converter/converter.h"

class ConverterTest : public ::testing::Test {
 protected:
  ConverterTest() = default;
  Converter converter;
};
```

Comment: Did you close `output_stream_` in `ConvertToBin()`?

Comment: This is not a correct way to write tests and testable code. You should alter your production code to so you could mock instances of `std::ifstream` and `std::ostream`. Then you could test any scenario: for example simulate failure in file creation.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen yes, i did.

Comment: Question is what this part of code `...` does? Maybe you can make your code more abstract and use `std::istream` and `std::ostream` whenever it is possible? Then in test you can just use `std::stringstream` instead of `std::fstream`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all Ok. In the project build system point uncorrect path to root directory. Thefore path to files were wrong.